# Arrow GameObject in Unity3d won't fly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have implemented a bow and arrow script in unity5. But the arrow doesn't fly off. Can someone suggest why this happens. I'm a beginner.

This is the Bow Script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Bow : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject arrow = null;
    private Vector3 fwd = Vector3.zero;




    public GameObject arrowPrefab = null;
    public int initialSpeed = 30;
    public GameObject launchPosition = null;
    public float waitTime = 0.1f;
    public LayerMask layerMask;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 1, layerMask))
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Fire();
            }
        }
    }



    private void Fire()
    {
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        arrow = (GameObject)Instantiate(arrowPrefab, launchPosition.transform.position, launchPosition.transform.rotation);
    }


}
```

This is the Arrow Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
```

> public class Arrow : MonoBehaviour {
>
> ```
>     private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
>     private Vector3 newPos;
>     private Vector3 oldPos;
>     private bool hasHit = false;
>     private Vector3 direction;
>     private RaycastHit hit;
>     private GameObject follow;
>
>     private Vector3 dir;
>     private float dist;
> ```

```
    public LayerMask layerMask;
    public float speed;
    public Transform arrowRotation;
    public float forceToApply;
    public float arrowGravity;


    void Start()
    {
        newPos = transform.position;
        oldPos = newPos;
        velocity = speed * transform.forward;
    }

    void update()
    {
        if (hasHit)
        {
            transform.position = follow.transform.position;
            transform.rotation = follow.transform.rotation;
            return;
        }

        newPos += (velocity + direction) * Time.deltaTime;
        dir = newPos - oldPos;
        dist = dir.magnitude;

        dir /= dist;

        if(dist > 0)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(oldPos,dir,out hit,dist,layerMask))
            {
                newPos = hit.point;

                if (hit.collider)
                {
                    if (hit.rigidbody)
                    {
                        GameObject hitpoint = (GameObject)Instantiate(new GameObject(), hit.point, transform.root.rotation);
                        hitpoint.transform.parent = hit.transform;
                        follow = hitpoint;
                        GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = true;
                        hit.rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(forceToApply * dir, hit.point);
                        hasHit = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        oldPos = transform.position;
        transform.position = newPos;
        velocity.y -= arrowGravity * Time.deltaTime;
        arrowRotation.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);

    }



}
```

Comment: I suggest working on solving the problem yourself first, and also adding what you've tried/failed, etc, to get a more positive response. It will also help you learn tricks in solving these things yourself! I hope that helps! :D

Comment: @andeart It works now. There's issue in the update method. It should start with capital. Silly me. I hope the script helps others. It works 100%. Thanks for the feedback:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare, but do not define 'direction' in your Arrow script. I suspect including it in the newPos calculation means nothing gets added.

Comment: Great your one slight worked. I mistakenly mispelled `"update"` method. Should be `"Update"`.

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way :)